# IntelliJ IDEA Caches resources (.xml, .sql) in project

Tags: configuration, intellij-idea

I have problem, that when I work on some project features and I edit xml, sql files, It's not enough to rerun the project, i need to execute complete clean and rebuild so changes are applied in the project. 
For example I've changed xml with app context for spring, and after rerun of the project, it didn't catch it up.

Is this caused by some hidden option in IDEA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing which comes to my mind is Settings -> General -> Synchronization -> check "Save files on frame deactivation". If it is unchecked, you should manually save files via Ctrl-S.